# not able to runn dependency main function

Tags: java, maven, reflection, jar, dependencies

I am having two java projects, **animal** project and **animal-test** project. In  **animal** project I am having an annotation interface called **Animal** like as shown below

**Animal.java**

```
package com.animal;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface Animal{
    String name();
}
```

Along with this I am having an interface **MakeSound.java** which has a method called **makesSound()**.

Now I have build and created  **animal** jar file including the dependencies, then I have imported **animal.jar** in my Second Project **animal-test**. I create a class called **AnimalTest.java** 
I now build and create a jar file **animal-test.jar** and when I run the jar file like **java -jar animal-test.jar** I got the following exception

```
no main manifest attribute, in animal-test.jar
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: Looks like the main class attribute is not present in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`  Can you check if the entry `Main-Class: com.animal.AnimalFinder` is present in the MANIFEST.MF file in the jar?

Comment: How are you creating the jar?

Comment: @JerinJoseph I am using` mvn clean install`

Comment: @JerinJoseph I am importing both jars, `animal-1.0.jar` and `animal-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. In `animal-1.0.jar` nothing is  there but in `animal-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I have `Main-Class: com.animal.AnimalFinder`

Comment: You would need the manifest in the animal test jar too.  Check my answer.

Comment: @JerinJoseph let me try with that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146686/discussion-between-alex-man-and-jerin-joseph).

Comment: sorry can't chat.

Comment: @JerinJoseph I got two jars `animal-1.0.jar` and `animal-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. When I run `java -jar animal-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I got `Error: Could not find or load main class com.animal.AnimalFinder`

Comment: Basically, you would need the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with the `Main-Class: com.animal.AnimalFinder` in the jar file you are trying to run.  So, you would just need to add the plugin to the pom.xml which builds the jar.

Comment: Ok.  Now you have run into a different problem.

Comment: As you've added the `animal-1.0.jar` as a local dependency.  The classes under `animal-1.0.jar` will not be present inside `animal-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.  Hence it is not able to find the `com.animal.AnimalFinder`

Comment: You need to add the `animal-1.0.jar` to the class path when you run.

Comment: Run it as `java -cp animal-1.0.jar -jar animal-test.jar`

Comment: @JerinJoseph When I run `java -cp animal-1.0.jar -jar animal-test.jar` I got `no main manifest attribute, in animal-1.0.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the plugin to create the MANIFEST file in the pom.xml for animal-test too.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.animal.AnimalFinder</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Let me try with this

Comment: I got two jars `animal-1.0.jar` and `animal-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. When I run `java -jar animal-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I got `Error: Could not find or load main class com.animal.AnimalFinder`

Comment: Can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582091/one-jar-with-one-class-and-main-class-from-dependecy-jar