# one jar with one class and main class from dependecy jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, maven-assembly-plugin, onejar

I am having one project with two classes named as **Test1** and **Test2**.

Both **Test1** and **Test2** are not main classes. Now I have one dependency named **cloudexe.jar** which has a main class **ClassExecuter**. Now my issue is that I want **ClassExecuter** as the main class for both **test1.jar** and **test2.jar**.

**test1.jar** should contains only Test1 class and all its dependencies including **cloudexe.jar** similarly **test2.jar** should contains only **Test2** class and all its dependencies including **cloudexe.jar**

Now when my package my pom.xml I gets test1.jar and test2.jar but I am getting like as shown below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.uber.Test1.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1678)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.run(Boot.java:339)
        at com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot.main(Boot.java:166)
```

My **pom.xml** is given below

```
<build>
  <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>com.jolira</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>build-first</id>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.uber.Test1</mainClass>
            <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
            <classifier>onejar</classifier>
            <filename>test1.jar</filename>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>one-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>build-second</id>
          <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.uber.Test2</mainClass>
            <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
            <classifier>onejar</classifier>
            <filename>test2.jar</filename>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>one-jar</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<pluginRepositories>
  <pluginRepository>
     <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
     <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
  </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a parent with 2 child projects :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>test1</module>
    <module>test2</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

Then you have 2 projects test1 and test2 projects, they will produce jars, use the shade pluging to have it execute the main class ClassExecuter :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>test1</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
      ... all your dependencies including cloudexe.jar
  </dependencies>

<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>....ClassExecuter</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in which `pom.xml` I will define the modules `<modules>
    <module>test1</module>
    <module>test2</module>
  </modules>`

Comment: You need too look at maven multi module projects.  Your have a parent, then 2 children.  Each child is in it's own directory.  When the parent is built it will build each of it's children, in your case each child will have an executable jar in its target folder.

Comment: but for one class I need o create a module project.....if I am having 10 classes....then 10 module projects I need to create.....Is there any other solution

Comment: Essex can we do using `maven-assembly-plugin` and `onejar-maven-plugin`

Comment: This is the way I would do it, I think you need to look at your question again, explain why you want all these main classes.

Comment: I have only one main function class which is  `ClassExecuter.java` which is having the implementation, `Test1.java` and `Test2.java` classes does not have main methods but have some common method signature  lets say `start()` and this function is called within the `ClassExecuter` class using reflection